# How to redirect if token expired in flutter with http

Tags: flutter, dart, token

I have a problem where when the user's token expires it should return to the login page, but the case I experienced was that it didn't return to the login page, instead it gave an exception in the form of text 'Token Expired' in the widget.

is there something wrong with my code.

[image]

[image]

this is the code in the login page widget

```
 Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 45,
                      child: isLoading
                          ? Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                color: primaryColor,
                              ),
                            )
                          : CustomButtonFilled(
                              title: 'Login',
                              onPressed: () async {
                                final prefs =
                                    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                prefs.setString(Constant.token, '');
                                if (nimController.text.isEmpty ||
                                    passwordController.text.isEmpty) {
                                  showError('NIM/Password harus diisi');
                                } else {
                                  setState(() {
                                    isLoading = true;
                                  });
                                  User? user = await userProvider.login(
                                    nimController.text,
                                    passwordController.text,
                                  );
                                  setState(() {
                                    isLoading = false;
                                  });
                                  if (user == null) {
                                    showError('NIM/Password tidak sesuai!');
                                  } else {
                                    userProvider.user = user;
                                    // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                                    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                                      context,
                                      '/main',
                                      (route) => false,
                                    );
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                    ),
```

> call API login

```
 Future<User?> login(String nim, String password) async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;        try {
      var body = {
        'username': nim,
        'password': password,
      };
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(
          '$url/login_mhs',
        ),
        body: body,
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final token = jsonDecode(response.body)['data']['access_token'];
        await UtilSharedPreferences.setToken(token);
        print(token);
        return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

> widget splashscreen

```
Future<void> toLogin() async {
    Timer(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      () async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        String? token = prefs.getString(Constant.token);
        // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
          context,
          token != null ? AppRoute.mainRoute : AppRoute.loginRoute,
          arguments: token,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    toLogin();
  }
```

Comment: Can you print the value of token.toString and tell me the value printed?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r3z7qAyOz9BnSOj-mT5U8KNu7sFEIuti/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In your code you have it to go to loginRoute only and only if the token that is fetched from the sharedpreference is printed 'null'

Comment: how do i make it?

Comment: Inside Else { throw exception} add Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
          context,
         AppRoute.loginRoute,); and reset the token from shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you can modify the `toLogin()` function to check if the token is `empty` and navigate to the login page in that case:

```dart
Future<void> toLogin() async {
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback(
    (_) {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      String? token = prefs.getString(Constant.token);

      if (token == null || token.isEmpty) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, AppRoute.loginRoute);
      } else {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, AppRoute.mainRoute);
      } 
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: it stays like that, when i try to refresh the token. does not redirect to the login page

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bfizRRjPAjIu6VtQCc9v6zA4XXMFDOfE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what happens if you remove `throw Exception();`?

Comment: if remove thwor exception https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tnezxiS4A0xYIYr2dLXLkLH2D-AYg2yy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I suppose the Timer is the root of the issue because login happens 3 seconds after fetching bio data, I have updated the response and hope it solves the issue.

Comment: still not working bro

Comment: I think the call sequence is not correct,
make `getBiodata` return type nullable and remove `throw exception`.

Comment: how do i make it?

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the token as a String inside the shared preferences. That string will always be there and never expire. So when you do

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
          context,
          token != null ? AppRoute.mainRoute : AppRoute.loginRoute,
          arguments: token,
        );
```

It will never go to login page because the token is never null or empty. When you do post request to API, that is when it tells you the result where the token is expired, so you want to handle the page change after getting the results from the post request. So your code should be more like that:

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return UserBiodata.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Token Expired');
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed( context, AppRoute.loginRoute,);
  }
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gHxpXQ0fTaY2ZTO7w8PC1ngLtWUogm7o/view?usp=sharing